# refresh list coredata swifui

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

i maked core data and i fetch all data to List.
all working (add ,delete)
but! if the app inactive (back to background) and i open again to delete a row it crashes with error:

"Thread 1: "An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts."

Video problem: https://streamable.com/olqm7y

```
struct HistoryView: View {
  @State private var history: [HistoryList] = [HistoryList]()

  let coreDM: CoreDataManager
   
  var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
    return formatter
  }
   
  private func populateHistory(){
    history = coreDM.getAllHistory()
  }
   
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      VStack {
        if !history.isEmpty {
          List {
            ForEach(history, id: \.self) { historyList in
              HStack {
                Text(dateFormatter.string(from: historyList.dateFlash ?? Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)))
                Text("\(historyList.timerFlash)s")
                  .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
              }
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexset in
              indexset.forEach { index in
                let history = history[index]
                coreDM.deleteHistory(history: history)
                populateHistory()
              }
            })
          }.refreshable {
            populateHistory()
            print("## Refresh History List")
          }
        } else {
          Text("History Flashlight is Empty")
        }
      }
      .onAppear {
        populateHistory()
        print("OnAppear")
      }
    }.navigationTitle("History Flashlight")
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
  }
}

struct HistoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    HistoryView(coreDM: CoreDataManager())
  }
}
```

CoreDataManager:

```
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {
    
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(){
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description , error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Core Data Store failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveHistory(timeFlash: Int, dateFlash: Date) {
        let history = HistoryList(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        history.timerFlash = Int16(timeFlash)
        history.dateFlash = dateFlash
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("failed to save \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func getAllHistory() -> [HistoryList] {
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<HistoryList> = HistoryList.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func deleteHistory(history: HistoryList) {
        persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(history)
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save context \(error)")
        }
    }
}

public extension NSManagedObject {

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: name, in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }
}
```

why?

I looked at the stackoverflow site but didn't find a solution

Comment: There is a big mistake. You cannot fetch data inside a loop multiple times while deleting items in the context. By the way there is no need to refetch the data. Delete `populateHistory()` in `indexset.forEach` or at least refetch the data once **after** the loop

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to swiftui, I deleted it and it's still the same problem i upload video: https://streamable.com/olqm7y

Comment: `let coreDM: CoreDataManager`, how is this set?

Comment: I guess the problem is related to `CoreDataManager` rather than to the code in the question.

Comment: I updated it in the question and added coreDataManager

Comment: You didn’t answer my question but know that you can not create more than one instance of CoreDataManager in your app or you will be in trouble.